# SSH Tunnel for Python MySQLdb connection with public key

Tags: python, ssh, mysql-python, public-key

I am trying to use MySQLdb but I didn't find anywhere how to make connection throught a SSH Tunel using a public key. Anybody can please guide me throught this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you need first to create a tunnel, so in your shell do:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyfile.pem -L 3306:127.0.0.1:22 <hostIP>
```

and change your Python code to something like the following for connecting:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='username', passwd='pass', db='DB')
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried those both : ssh -i C:\\id_dsa -L 3306:127.0.0.1:22 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and ssh -i 'C:\\id_dsa' -L 3306:127.0.0.1:22 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but i got the error code SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Note that it is normal that my file doesn't have any extension, that's the way it was give it to me.

Comment: Oh I didn't think you were on Windows, let me search the ssh command for that.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza I'm on windows too, how do i SSH , i have putty running and can connect to phpmyadmin from browser already